# Crawling Twitter API for specific tweets

Tags: python, function, twitter, web-crawler, twitterapi-python

I am trying to crawl twitter for specific keywords, which I have made into the array

```
keywords = ["art", "railway", "neck"]
```

I am trying to search for these words in a specific location, which I have written as

```
PLACE_LAT = 29.7604
PLACE_LON = -95.3698
PLACE_RAD = 200
```

I have then tried to apply a function to find at least 200 tweets, but I know that only 100 can be searched with each query. My code so far is below, however, this code did not work.

```
def retrieve_tweets(api, keyword, batch_count, total_count, latitude, longitude, radius):
    """
    collects tweets using the Twitter search API

    api:         Twitter API instance
    keyword:     search keyword
    batch_count: maximum number of tweets to collect per each request
    total_count: maximum number of tweets in total
    """


    # the collection of tweets to be returned
    tweets_unfiltered = []
    tweets = []

    # the number of tweets within a single query
    batch_count = str(batch_count)

    '''
    You are required to insert your own code where instructed to perform the first query to Twitter API.
    Hint: revise the practical session on Twitter API on how to perform query to Twitter API.
    '''
    # per the first query, to obtain max_id_str which will be used later to query sub
    resp = api.request('search/tweets', {'q': keywords,
                                         'count': '100',
                                         'lang':'en',
                                         'result_type':'recent',
                                         'geocode':'{PLACE_LAT},{PLACE_LONG},{PLACE_RAD}mi'.format(latitude, longitude, radius)})

    # store the tweets in a list

    # check first if there was an error
    if ('errors' in resp.json()):
        errors = resp.json()['errors']
        if (errors[0]['code'] == 88):
            print('Too many attempts to load tweets.')
            print('You need to wait for a few minutes before accessing Twitter API again.')

    if ('statuses' in resp.json()):
        tweets_unfiltered += resp.json()['statuses']
        tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets_unfiltered if ((tweet['retweeted'] != True) and ('RT @' not in tweet['text']))]

        # find the max_id_str for the next batch
        ids = [tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets_unfiltered]
        max_id_str = str(min(ids))

        # loop until as many tweets as total_count is collected
        number_of_tweets = len(tweets)
        while number_of_tweets < total_count:

            resp = api.request('search/tweets', {'q': keywords,
                                                 'count': '50',
                                                 'lang':'en',
                                                 'result_type': 'recent',
                                                 'max_id': max_id_str,
                                                 'geocode':'{PLACE_LAT},{PLACE_LONG},{PLACE_RAD}mi'.format(latitude, longitude, radius)}
                          )

            if ('statuses' in resp.json()):
                tweets_unfiltered += resp.json()['statuses']
                tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets_unfiltered if ((tweet['retweeted'] != True) and ('RT @' not in tweet['text']))]

                ids = [tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets_unfiltered]
                max_id_str = str(min(ids))

                number_of_tweets = len(tweets)

            print("{} tweets are collected for keyword {}. Last tweet created at {}".format(number_of_tweets, 
                                                                                    keyword, 
                                                                                    tweets[number_of_tweets-1]['created_at']))
    return tweets
```

I only needed to write code where it said # Insert your code. What changes do I need to make to get this to work

```
def retrieve_tweets(api, keyword, batch_count, total_count, latitude, longitude, radius):
    """
    collects tweets using the Twitter search API

    api:         Twitter API instance
    keyword:     search keyword
    batch_count: maximum number of tweets to collect per each request
    total_count: maximum number of tweets in total
    """


    # the collection of tweets to be returned
    tweets_unfiltered = []
    tweets = []

    # the number of tweets within a single query
    batch_count = str(batch_count)

    '''
    You are required to insert your own code where instructed to perform the first query to Twitter API.
    Hint: revise the practical session on Twitter API on how to perform query to Twitter API.
    '''
    # per the first query, to obtain max_id_str which will be used later to query sub
    resp = api.request('search/tweets', {'q': #INSERT YOUR CODE
                                         'count': #INSERT YOUR CODE
                                         'lang':'en',
                                         'result_type':'recent',
                                         'geocode':'{},{},{}mi'.format(latitude, longitude, radius)})

    # store the tweets in a list

    # check first if there was an error
    if ('errors' in resp.json()):
        errors = resp.json()['errors']
        if (errors[0]['code'] == 88):
            print('Too many attempts to load tweets.')
            print('You need to wait for a few minutes before accessing Twitter API again.')

    if ('statuses' in resp.json()):
        tweets_unfiltered += resp.json()['statuses']
        tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets_unfiltered if ((tweet['retweeted'] != True) and ('RT @' not in tweet['text']))]

        # find the max_id_str for the next batch
        ids = [tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets_unfiltered]
        max_id_str = str(min(ids))

        # loop until as many tweets as total_count is collected
        number_of_tweets = len(tweets)
        while number_of_tweets < total_count:

            resp = api.request('search/tweets', {'q': #INSERT YOUR CODE
                                             'count': #INSERT YOUR CODE
                                             'lang':'en',
                                             'result_type':  #INSERT YOUR CODE
                                             'max_id': max_id_str,
                                             'geocode': #INSERT YOUR CODE
                          )

            if ('statuses' in resp.json()):
                tweets_unfiltered += resp.json()['statuses']
                tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets_unfiltered if ((tweet['retweeted'] != True) and ('RT @' not in tweet['text']))]

                ids = [tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets_unfiltered]
                max_id_str = str(min(ids))

                number_of_tweets = len(tweets)

            print("{} tweets are collected for keyword {}. Last tweet created at {}".format(number_of_tweets, 
                                                                                    keyword, 
                                                                                    tweets[number_of_tweets-1]['created_at']))
    return tweets
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your question or issue? I didn't see any in your post.

A couple of suggestions... Remove `lang` and `result_type` parameters from your request. Because you are using `geocode` you should not expect very many results since hardly anyone turns location on when they tweet.

Also, rather than using `max_id` parameter, you may want to look at the [`TwitterPager`](http://geduldig.github.io/TwitterAPI/twitterpager.html) class which takes care of this for you. Here is an example: https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/page_tweets.py.